# AngularJS grouping values and adding them together in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create a total sum of a group in AngularJS. I'm using http to get the results into a html table :

```
    $http({method: 'GET', url: urlpurchasing}).success(function(data) {

               $scope.purchasing = data;

             })
```

Which gives the below result :
[image]

I want to make a new column called "total stock" and add all of the "Quantity sold" for each group, so for all which have a Desc of the same value i want there "quantity sold" to be added up. For example, the 3 purple rows at the bottom would have "607" in there "total sold" column.

I tried to loop through the data with an angular for-each and add each one up but this involves creating a second array and any kind of filter or change in the main table changes the indexes and it mixes up. Appreciate any assistance.

**edit**

This is what i have so far (but the totals are incrementing each time :

```
  $http({method: 'GET', url: urlpurchasing}).success(function(data) {


                                var t = 0;

                                 angular.forEach(data, function(obj){


                                    if($scope.code == obj.GroupCode){

                                       }
                                       else
                                       {
                                        $scope.code = obj.GroupCode;
                                        t = 0;

                                       }

                                     t = (t + parseInt(obj.QuantitySold));
                                     obj.total = t;


                                  });

                                    $scope.purchasing = data;


                     })
```

Here is the PHP :

```
<?php

require_once('sqlconnect.php');
$sqlQuery = "select StockCode,Description,QuantityInStock,QuantitySold,NetAmountSold,GroupCode,color from purchasing order by Description desc"; 
$result = $unity_connection->query($sqlQuery);

$json1 = array();
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $json1[] = $rows;
}   

    echo json_encode($json1);

?>
```

Comment: Do you have control over the backend as well? If so, I'd let the database do the work rather than doing any kind of looping client-side.

Comment: Yeah but it's for a visual stock representation and the user can change the values, id have to update every row in the db for any and every change so i decided against that

Comment: Um, I'd assume the database can do calculations as part of the query. What database are you using?

Comment: I'm using MySQL and PHP

Comment: Can you post your query?

Comment: Edited it mate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144955/discussion-between-gaz-smith-and-mike-feltman).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use MySQL, but standard SQL should do the trick here:

```
SELECT
    purchasing.stockcode,
    purchasing.description,
    purchasing.quantityinstock,
    purchasing.quantitysold,
    purchasing.netamountsold,
    purchasing.groupcode,
    purchasing.color,
    desc_summary.totalstock
FROM
    purchasing join (select description, sum(quantitysold) as TotalStock from purchasing group by descrption) desc_summary on purchasing.description = desc_summary.description 
ORDER BY purchasing.description DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by multiple ways, either to create extra variable for `total` in your `controller scope` or directly in your `data\json` as well., or by extending `$scope.purchansing`

OR, if you don't want any further `$scope` property, then you can invoke a function at run time to calculate the `total for each group.`.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utxLqev6/) in which I tried with run time function which checks for group total per group.

**Updated** [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rwdeo0uy/) to extend your scope data in controller.

Comment: I cant do it that way, i have around 500 rows in the data object it just crashes

Comment: As I mentioned in answer, you can also extend `$scope.purchansing`, while fetching data inside `.success`, and create another property 'groupTotalSold'

Comment: Hi, i tried that but the values just increment (eg 60, 120, 150, 270 etc)

Comment: Ideally, such calculation to be done from backend, but if you need to do it, then you can extend the properties as well. I updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rwdeo0uy/), .